# Migrate php codes from 5.4 to php 7

Tags: php, version, upgrade, smarty

Currently, I'm working with php 5.4, and would like to move to 7 or 7.2. While running my code on server php 7.2, its throws the syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW). It depends upon the assigned class with & operator.

I used this kind of code overall project. It not possible to remove all the functionalities.

```
$instance =& new Configure();
```

May I achieve running my project under php 7.2 without removing the assigning operator?

Comment: I've never seen a `=&` next to each other.. what did that do in 5.4? Didn't see it in my 5.6 travels

Comment: That looks odd. Are you creating a new instance and trying to store it as a reference?

Comment: Yes exactly @magnus. And this done by a year ago with php 5.4 & now I need to run this under php 7.2.

Comment: But why create a reference when you're doing `new`? I might be missing something but can't see the purpose?

Comment: This done by a year ago while used php 5.4 that time & now I need to run this under php 7.2.

Comment: That feature was actually deprecated back in PHP 5.3. It was then removed in 7.0 (even 5.0 throws a "strict standard" message about it). The reason you didn't see anything about it was probably that your error_reporting-level doesn't include deprecation warnings. Here's a [demo](https://3v4l.org/taTBB) (check the "eol versions"-box to include older PHP versions). A good idea is to have error_reporting set to E_ALL while developing to catch things like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since PHP 5, new returns a reference automatically, so using =& in this context is deprecated and produces an E_DEPRECATED message in PHP 5.3 and later, and an E_STRICT message in earlier versions. As of PHP 7.0 it is syntactically invalid.

[PHP references](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php)

So you have to change your code.